# SQL Table Join with 3 select values

Tags: sql, sql-server, report, join

I need a little help on a sql table join. I am pulling from 2 tables. A patient table and a patient_clin_tran table which houses apts. I need to view all of the patients one of our providers has seen and I was able to pull that from the clin_tran (apts with the following code)

```
select 
distinct p.patient_id,
p.attending_id

from patient_clin_tran p

where p.attending_id = 00000380
order by p.patient_id
```

Now I also need to see which of these patients are active in this table.

```
select

p.patient_id,
p.case_status

from patient p
```

The patient_id is the same. Can I join these? If I am able to join I will then sort the 2 statuses in crystal reports based on p.case_status which I know how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can join these, like this:

```
select 
    distinct c.patient_id,
        c.attending_id,
        p.case_status

    from patient_clin_tran c
    join patient p
        on c.patient_id = p.patient_id

    where c.attending_id = 00000380
    order by c.patient_id
```

you'd have to give the tables different aliases, I changed the 'p' to a 'c' for your `patient_clin_tran`

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: yes, after the `c.attending` I missed that... sorry, good catch though

Comment: O and the order by had a little typo, but I think that did it! Thanks a ton!